# Angular router outlet incorrect height after adding router animation

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am trying to add router animations for my angular project, I have added an animation but for the animation needs to work I am adding absolute position for the selector inside the router-outlet tag.

Which is creating the problem and the component inside the outlet is not taking it's full content height and getting chopped of from the bottom.

**Animation**

```
export const routerAnimation = trigger('routerAnimation', [
    transition('* => *', [
        query(':enter', [style({ opacity: 0 })], { optional: true }),
        group([
            query(':leave', [animate(300, style({ opacity: 0 }))], {
                optional: true
            }),
            query(
                ':enter',
                [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate(300, style({ opacity: 1 }))],
                { optional: true }
            )
        ])
    ])
]);
```

**HTML Layout**

```
<div class="admin-layout-outer">
    <admin-header></admin-header>
    <admin-sidebar></admin-sidebar>
    <div class="admin-layout-inner">
        <ng-scrollbar
            [visibility]="'hover'"
            [appearance]="'compact'"
            [autoHeightDisabled]="false"
            [viewClass]="'custom-scrollbar'"
            [pointerEventsMethod]="'scrollbar'"
            [trackClass]="'custom-scrollbar-track'"
            [thumbClass]="'custom-scrollbar-thumb'"
        >
            <div
                class="admin-layout-content"
                [@routerAnimation]="
                    adminLayout.isActivated ? adminLayout.activatedRoute : ''
                "
            >
                <router-outlet #adminLayout="outlet"></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </ng-scrollbar>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Layout CSS**

```
.admin-layout-outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: var(--white);
}
.admin-layout-inner {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-left: 225px;
}
.admin-layout-content {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 130px);
}
::ng-deep .admin-layout-content > :last-child {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the example in [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/route-animations)

See that the animation is like

```
trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('*<=> *', [

      //you should include this
      style({ position: 'relative' }),
      query(':enter, :leave', [
        style({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%'
      })
      ], { optional: true }),

      //now you add your query enter
      query(':enter', [...])

      //interesting you can add leave animateChild
      query(':leave', animateChild(), { optional: true }),

      //here your animation group
      group([...your group animation...])
 ]);
```